# Problema al insertar un Nodo en un grafo C

Tags: c, teoría-de-grafos

Tengo que mapear un laberinto desde dentro y decidí usar grafos ( Nunca los he usado, estoy aprendiendo sobre la marcha ) pero cuando intento insertar un Nodo al grafo, el programa se cierra sin mandar ningún tipo de error ( Creo que estoy usando memoria no declarada o algo así).

Así se esta declarando el Nodo;

```
typedef struct Nodo{

    int Valor;                      // 1 si es interseccion
                                    // 0 si es que es recta
    struct Nodo *Der;
    struct Nodo *Arb;
    struct Nodo *Izq;
    struct Nodo *Abj;

    struct Nodo *Padre;

}Nodo;
```

La creación del nodo en la cual se reserva la memoria:

```
Nodo *CrearNodo( Nodo *padre , int n ){

    Nodo *nuevoNodo = (Nodo *) malloc( sizeof( Nodo ));

    nuevoNodo->Der = NULL;
    nuevoNodo->Izq = NULL;
    nuevoNodo->Arb = NULL;
    nuevoNodo->Abj = NULL;

    nuevoNodo->Valor = n;

    return nuevoNodo;
}
```

Y esta es la parte del codigo que está fallando:

```
    Nodo *InsertarNodo( Nodo *Grafo, int dir, int n  ){
    Nodo *nuevoNodo = CrearNodo( NULL , n );
    if( Grafo == NULL ){
        Grafo = nuevoNodo;
        PostNodo[y][x] = Grafo;
    }else{
        if( dir == 1 ){
            y--;
            if( PostNodo[y][x] != NULL ){
                Grafo->Arb = (Nodo *)&PostNodo[y][x];
                Grafo->Arb->Abj = Grafo->Abj;
            }else{
                printf("1\n");
                nuevoNodo->Abj = Grafo;
                printf("2\n");
                Grafo->Arb = nuevoNodo;
                printf("3\n");
                PostNodo[y][x] = Grafo->Arb;
            }
            return Grafo->Arb;

        }else if( dir == 2 ){
            x--;
            if( PostNodo[y][x] != NULL ){
                Grafo->Izq = (Nodo *)&PostNodo[y][x];
                Grafo->Izq->Der = Grafo->Izq;
            }else{
                nuevoNodo->Izq = Grafo;
                Grafo->Der = nuevoNodo;
                PostNodo[y][x] = Grafo->Izq;
            }
            return Grafo->Izq;

        }else if( dir == 3 ){
            x++;
            if( PostNodo[y][x] != NULL ){
                Grafo->Der = (Nodo *)&PostNodo[y][x];
                Grafo->Der->Izq = Grafo->Izq;
            }else{
                nuevoNodo->Der = Grafo;
                Grafo->Izq = nuevoNodo;
                PostNodo[y][x] = Grafo->Der;
            }
            return Grafo->Der;

        }else if( dir == 4 ){
            y++;
            if( PostNodo[y][x] != NULL ){
                Grafo->Abj = (Nodo *)&PostNodo[y][x];
                Grafo->Abj->Arb = Grafo->Abj;
            }else{
                nuevoNodo->Arb = Grafo;
                Grafo->Abj = nuevoNodo;
                PostNodo[y][x] = Grafo->Abj;
            }
            return Grafo->Abj;
        }
    }
    free( nuevoNodo );
}
```

específicamente esta parte "Grafo->Arb = nuevoNodo;"

Comment: Buenas tardes @Frijolito. Sería muy bueno que pusieras la traza completa del error así como la función completa que genera el fallo pues no se ven de que tipo son las variables y así esta dificil poder reproducir el error.

Comment: @AlvaroC.voy a editar el post original y poner el resto del codigo ya que es extenso, gracias por responder

Comment: Así a bote pronto, en la función CrearNodo() no deberías indicar al nuevo nodo cual es su padre? Algo como  nuevoNodo->Padre = padre;

Comment: @user3733164 el padre del nodo depende de la dirección donde vas a doblar en la laberinto puedo el padre puede ser el nodo del al lado como el de la izquierda, derecha arriba o abajo pero se me olvido saca esa parte en el codigo

Comment: Hola @Frijolito. Si es como lo mencionas ¿para que pasas por parámetro en la funcion CrearNodo al nodo padre? Lo digo por que estas pasando una variable que no usas en esa función. Por otro lado sería bueno entender ¿que representa Izq, Der, Arb y Aba? ¿son las posibles direcciones a tomar en el laberinto?

Comment: @AlvaroC.El nodo padre esta para saber cual era tu posición anterior por si en el laberinto era un camino cerrado volver usando los padres (aun no incluía el backtrack por eso no se estaba usando pero si estaba declarada, fue error mio no explicar eso ). Izq, Der, Arb, Abj significa arriba derecha, izquierda etc y son los posibles movimiento del micromouse, aunque ya solucione el problema y era que al crear el primer nodo el cual es el nodo inicial no devolvía la post actual y generaba errores porque esa memoria existía pero no significaba nada, Gracias por comentar a todos <3

Answer (score 1):

Falta contexto para saber exactamente cual es el problema. Sería muy útil ver cómo y dónde se usa la función `InsertarNodo`.

Pero aún con la falta de contexto, las funciones `InsertarNodo` y `CrearNodo` ya denotan fallos de diseño que dan pistas de dónde podría estar el fallo.

#### Datos no inicializados.

La función `Nodo *CrearNodo( Nodo *padre , int n )` no usa el puntero `padre`, no se si es error u omisión pero lo que si podemos ver es que no le das un valor inicial:

```
Nodo *CrearNodo( Nodo *padre , int n ){

    Nodo *nuevoNodo = (Nodo *) malloc( sizeof( Nodo ));

    nuevoNodo->Valor = n;

    nuevoNodo->Der = NULL;
    nuevoNodo->Izq = NULL;
    nuevoNodo->Arb = NULL;
    nuevoNodo->Abj = NULL;

    nuevoNodo->Padre = NULL; // <--- ¿Qué debe ir aquí?

    return nuevoNodo;
}
```

En la línea resaltada ¿Qué debería ir?:

- `nuevoNodo->Padre = NULL;`
- `nuevoNodo->Padre = padre;`

No veo en el código compartido que estés enlazando el `nuevoNodo` con su padre, dado que tampoco le das valor inicial se quedará con valores indeterminados y el acceder a esos valores indeterminados provocará un fallo como el que describes. Te aconsejo inicializar todos los datos del `Nodo` a valores nulos y comprobarlos antes de des-referenciar:

```
Nodo *CrearNodo( int n ){ // Sin 'padre', se le asignará padre fuera

    Nodo *nuevoNodo = (Nodo *) malloc( sizeof( Nodo ));

    // Todos bytes del objeto a 0
    memset(nuevoNodo, 0, sizeof( Nodo ));

    nuevoNodo->Valor = n;
    return nuevoNodo;
}
```

Externamente podrás des-referenciar el padre en base a si existe o no:

```
// Sin inicializar a 0, este código no es válido.
if (nodo->Padre)
    printf("%d", nodo->Padre->Valor);
```

#### Datos no cambiados.

Por otro lado, la función `InsertarNodo` recibe un puntero a `Nodo` (llamado `Grafo`) por copia, esto significa que cualquier cambio que se realice sobre ese puntero no se verá reflejado fuera de la función:

```
Nodo *n = NULL;
Nodo *o = InsertarNodo( n, 1, 2 );
printf("%d", n->Valor); // <---- Fallo en tiempo de ejecución: 'n' sigue siendo 'NULL'.
```

#### Función que acaba sin devolver nada.

La función `InsertarNodo` un problema adicional: una ruta de ejecución finaliza sin devolver valor alguno cuando el segundo parámetro es mayor a 4 o menor a 1, provocando también fallos en tiempo de ejecución:

```
Nodo *n = NULL;
Nodo *o = InsertarNodo( n, 42, 2 );
printf("%d", o->Valor); // <---- Fallo en tiempo de ejecución: no se sabe lo que es 'o'.
```

También `InsertarNodo` acaba sin devolver nada, en caso de pasar `NULL` como primer parámetro, para ser peor: justo antes de finalizar la función borra los datos creados que *presuntamente* se habían guardado en `Grafo`.

#### Problemas de estilo y uso.

Abusas de variables globales como `PostNodo`, `y` y `x`; eso hace que tu código sea difícil de seguir. Por otro lado repites mucho código, lo que complica el mantenimiento y la comprensión.

---

Resuelve los problemas mencionados y comenta si el código pasa a funcionar.